# DOJO Button within A Grid

Tags: button, dojo, grid

I am trying to get the dojo button that is within the data grid to use styling. Currently it does not use the styling.

HTML:

```
<table dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" class="soria" id="grid1" jsId="grid1" elasticView="2" store="theStore" selectionMode="single" query="{grid1:'*'}">
  <thead>
     <TR>
       <th field="0" formatter="getButton">Show value</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
```

javascript:

```
function getButton(item){
   return "<button class=/"soria/" dojoType=\"dijit.form.Button\" onClick=\"\">Button</button>";
}
```

Comment: I think you are going to have to provide some more details then this.  What is not working?  The button, the styling?  What isn't working about styling?

Comment: The button does load and if I manually parse the widget that is created it does take on the soria theme. However if there is any manipulation of the grid the theme is lost.

Comment: well isnt the theme dependent upon the theme you set on the grid or the body element of the page? (ive never tried mixing and matching before)

Comment: The theme of the whole page is soria. I am not trying to mix them I just want the button to have the soria theme when I dynamically load it into the grid. I have looked into it some more and I think the upgrade to 1.4 will solve this issue. I will see.... hopefully it does not break everything else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more info as suggested - like is this being utilized within the custom dijit framework or are you jsut trying to produce a button didjit on the fly?

Im going to assume the later for now so...

1.) You need to reparse the element if you want dynamically added elements created outside the dijit infrastructure to be turned into dijits.

2.) #1 doesnt make sense because if you are doing it on the fly you should be using the javascript programmiatc creation and adding it to the DOM instead of just returning html, ie:
`return new dijit.Form.Button()`